# How to trigger screen reader annoucements when focusing an already focused HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I'm trying to achieve the following: given a focusable HTML element, I want screen readers to announce it every time I call `focus()` on it. The announcement should happen even when the element gets focused several times in a row, i.e. even if the element was *already* focused before applying focus on it. Can anyone please help me with that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What's the purpose exactly ? What is for an element ? IF updates are frequent, probably that a separate element with aria-live would be more appropriate. The aria-live element doesn't need to take focus for the updates to be announced.